# .tlb registration problems for using

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Hi I'm trying to register .tlb file but when I run regsvr32 it is giving this error

```
The Module "name.tlb" may not compatible with the version of windows that you're running.check if the module is compatible with an X86(32-bit) or X64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot register a type library with Regsvr32.exe.  There is no universal helper program to do that, although some programmers have discovered regtlibv12.exe by accident.  That is a bad accident.  It is always the job of a COM server to register its own type library and only if needed.   You do *that* with Regsvr32, a DLL or OCX file.  Or the installer for the COM server.  That server always needs to be installed to actually use the type library.

Answer (score 1):

Regsvr32 requires a dynamic link library with a an entry point of DLLRegisterServer. TLB files are type library files and are not executable code. They are metadata about COM interfaces and types. Regsvr32 cannot register that file because it cannot be loaded as an executable.

Comment: but when I gave reference to that .tlb in windows app it is producing a dll file and when I try to register that dll it is giving error dllserver was not found

Comment: Try to use [RegASM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in visual studio command prompt instead.

Comment: I did run RegASM it was successful but it is giving this error Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {ID} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Comment: Are you running on a 32 bit or 64 bit OS ?

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct regsvr32. There is both a 64bit and 32bit version. If your COM object is 32bit then you will need to use the 32bit regsvr32 located in windows\syswow64.